# Find the 100th derivative of $x \sinh(2x)$

Tags: derivatives, summation, binomial-coefficients

If $f(x) = x \sinh(2x)$, find $f^{({100})}(x)$.

**My (Incorrect) working so far:**

Using Leibniz' Formula for derivatives:
$$(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$

$$(x\sinh(2x))^{(100)}=\sum_{k=0}^{100}{100\choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}=$$

Since the second derivative of $x$ is $0$...

$$=\sum_{k=0}^1{2\choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$

$$={2\choose 0}(x)(\sinh(2x))+{2\choose 1}(1)(2\cosh(2x))$$

$$=4x \sinh(2x)+4 \cosh(2x)$$

This is my answer and it is not correct. What do I need to change to make it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\binom20x\sinh(2x)=x\sinh(x)\neq4x\sinh(x)$ I didn't know that formula, but this is a start.

Comment: Do you mean $xsinh(2x)$?

Comment: The purpose of this question is to use Leibniz' formula

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's kind of ironic to have a mistake in a correction... `:S`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial coefficient in the Leibniz formula should be ${100\choose k}$ and not ${2\choose k}$.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better method, perhaps, if your aim is to evaluate this at $x=0$. Of course, other methods are required if you want the derivative $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. These have already been discussed in the comments and answers. Regardless this is a good way to 'check' whether you haven't made any computational mistakes along the way!

The Taylor expansion gives $x\cdot \frac{f^{99}(0)\cdot x^{99}}{99!} = \frac{g^{100}(0)\cdot x^{100}}{100!}$ where $f(x) = \sinh(2x)$ and $g(x) = x\cdot \sinh(2x)$.

Now $f^{99}(0) = 2^{99}\cdot \cosh(2\cdot 0) = 2^{99}$ and so $g^{100}(0) = 100\cdot 2^{99}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd like the answer to use Leibniz' formula. I should have made that clear.

Comment: Well this is a good check, since then you know that the coefficient of $\cosh(2x)$ is $100\cdot 2^{99}$ as the other answerer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler is using the formula $$\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2.$$